# jface/swt Tree refresh issue on Windows XP

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a desktop application built on SWT. I have a tree that is enclosed in a ScrolledComposite. This piece of code in the application is supposed to refresh the ui component.

```
aTreeViewer.setInput(this.items) //items is an array list of relevant objects
```

But it behaves weirdly on Windows XP and Windows 7. In Win XP, it returns with a  hard ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception that affects the behavior of my application.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 46
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree._getItem(Tree.java:254)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree._getItem(Tree.java:248)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.findCell(Tree.java:2703)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_MOUSEMOVE(Tree.java:6806)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4575)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5958)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
```

Whereas on Win 7, it appears to return from the SWT layer with this message that seems to be a RunTimeException which prints on my eclipse console but in no way effects the behavior of the application. Meaning, the application was working fine.

```
Ignored reentrant call while viewer is busy. This is only logged once per viewer instance, but similar calls will still be ignored.
java.lang.RuntimeException
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.checkBusy(ColumnViewer.java:763)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:541)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1490)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwList.basicRefresh(EwList.java:86)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwTableList.basicRefresh(EwTableList.java:75)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwList.refresh(EwList.java:402)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwTableList.columnsChanged(EwTableList.java:115)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwTableColumn.updateWidget(EwTableColumn.java:377)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwTableColumn.width(EwTableColumn.java:407)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.WkTableWidget.doAutoSizeColumns(WkTableWidget.java:244)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.WkTableWidget.autoSizeColumns(WkTableWidget.java:87)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.WkTableWidget.processResizedEvent(WkTableWidget.java:437)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwList$3.controlResized(EwList.java:449)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:235)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5795)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1442)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5859)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetScrollInfo(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.updateScrollBar(Tree.java:5660)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1589)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.WM_SIZE(Scrollable.java:316)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_SIZE(Composite.java:1662)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_SIZE(Tree.java:7137)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4603)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5958)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1534)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5408)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4616)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5958)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.ShowScrollBar(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_SIZE(Tree.java:7124)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4603)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5958)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1534)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(Control.java:5408)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4616)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5958)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1534)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5958)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3385)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.createItem(Tree.java:2104)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.<init>(TreeItem.java:203)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.<init>(TreeItem.java:91)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createNewRowPart(TreeViewer.java:809)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.newItem(TreeViewer.java:315)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:847)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:823)
       at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:797)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:768)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1548)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:833)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$5.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1532)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1525)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwList.refreshItems(EwList.java:439)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwTableList.refreshItems(EwTableList.java:514)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwTableTree.refreshItems(EwTableTree.java:275)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwList.itemsHaveChanged(EwList.java:345)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwLinearList.itemsHaveChanged(EwLinearList.java:200)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.EwList.setItems(EwList.java:549)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.cw.widgets.WkTableWidget.setItems(WkTableWidget.java:467)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.abt.widgets.compatibility.ExtendedList.widgetSetItems(ExtendedList.java:574)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.abt.widgets.compatibility.ExtendedList.setItems(ExtendedList.java:479)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.wk.table.compatibility.WkTableWidgetView.setItems(WkTableWidgetView.java:645)
       at com.misys.liq.ui.collateral.LiqCollateralAgreementTypeDefinitionController.updateAttributeGrid(LiqCollateralAgreementTypeDefinitionController.java:1712)
       at com.misys.liq.ui.collateral.LiqCollateralAgreementTypeDefinitionController.showCoreAttributes(LiqCollateralAgreementTypeDefinitionController.java:1730)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.utilities.ReflectionUtility.invoke(ReflectionUtility.java:754)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.utilities.ReflectionUtility.directPerform(ReflectionUtility.java:740)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.utilities.ReflectionUtility.perform(ReflectionUtility.java:605)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.compatibility.va.kernel.core.DirectedMessage.performAction(DirectedMessage.java:106)
       at com.misys.liq.infrastructure.EventObservableSupport.signalEvent(EventObservableSupport.java:21)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.abt.ObservableObject.primSignalEvent(ObservableObject.java:324)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.abt.ObservableObject.signalEvent(ObservableObject.java:398)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.abt.widgets.compatibility.BasicView.signalEvent(BasicView.java:1879)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.ui.abt.widgets.compatibility.ToggleButtonView$2.widgetSelected(ToggleButtonView.java:316)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
       at com.misys.liq.LoanIQ$13.value(LoanIQ.java:676)
       at com.sxsy.smtj.exceptions.ExceptionUtility.whenDo(ExceptionUtility.java:99)
       at com.misys.liq.LoanIQ.standardLiqEventLoop(LoanIQ.java:693)
       at com.misys.liq.LoanIQ.desktopTestManualLogIn(LoanIQ.java:924)
       at com.misys.liq.LoanIQ.mainClassic(LoanIQ.java:589)
       at com.misys.liq.LoanIQ.main(LoanIQ.java:309)
```

The first thing that struck my mind was to wrap my ui logic within Display.asyncExec's runnable and thereby I was able to fix the weird behavior in Win XP.

Although, I have no clue what has happened within the internals or even if my fix is right. It would be nice if someone who had experienced this kind of SWT weirdness could throw some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an swt/jface bug. The workaround for this issue is to set items as null before setting the actual object.

```
aTreeViewer.setInput(null);
aTreeViewer.setInput(this.items);
```